# T-SQL script crashing Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The following script is the what handles our log shipping routine. When we are running this manually, if for example LS is behind and we need to catch it up we are noticing after a large amount of time it crashes the management studio.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @RETURNCODE INT
DECLARE @DATE_STAMP NVARCHAR(30) 
DECLARE @DATABASE_NAME NVARCHAR(200) 
DECLARE @BACK_UP_PATH NVARCHAR(500) 
DECLARE @TRAN_BACK_UP_PATH NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @UNDO_FOLDER NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @BACK_UP_STRING NVARCHAR(1000) 
DECLARE @ALTER_STRING NVARCHAR(1000) 
DECLARE @FOLDER_NAME NVARCHAR(255) 
DECLARE @CMD NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @FILELIST TABLE (BACKUPFILE NVARCHAR(255)) 
DECLARE @LASTFULLBACKUP NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @BACKUP_FILE NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @MOVE_CMD NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @CONTROL_STRING NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @DRIVE Char(1)
DECLARE @MinMBFree int
DECLARE @MBfree int
DECLARE @Tries tinyint

SET @DRIVE = 'F'
SET @MinMBFree = '55504'

SET @BACK_UP_PATH = 'F:\MSSQL\Backup\'
SET @TRAN_BACK_UP_PATH = 'D:\TransactionLogs\'

SELECT @ReturnCode = 0

Truncate Table [dbo].[LogShip_Control]

DECLARE dbs CURSOR FOR
SELECT dbname FROM dbo.DBs2LogShip
ORDER BY dbname
OPEN dbs 
FETCH dbs INTO @DATABASE_NAME 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS != -1 
BEGIN

CMD:
SET @CMD = 'DIR /b ' + @TRAN_BACK_UP_PATH + @DATABASE_NAME +', NO OUTPUT'

INSERT INTO @fileList(backupFile) 
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @CMD
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO CMD

DECLARE backupFiles CURSOR FOR  
SELECT backupFile  
FROM @fileList 
WHERE backupFile LIKE @DATABASE_NAME + '%.TRN'  

OPEN backupFiles  

-- Loop through all the files for the database  
FETCH NEXT FROM backupFiles INTO @BACKUP_FILE  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
SET @MBfree = 0
CREATE TABLE #tbl_xp_fixeddrives
(Drive varchar(2) NOT NULL,
[MB free] int NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #tbl_xp_fixeddrives(Drive, [MB free])
EXEC master.sys.xp_fixeddrives

SELECT @MBfree = [MB free]
FROM #tbl_xp_fixeddrives 
WHERE Drive = @Drive

IF @MBfree < @MinMBFree
BEGIN
RAISERROR ('*** ERROR *** - Insufficient disk space.', 16, 1)
GOTO SKIPPER
END
DROP TABLE #tbl_xp_fixeddrives

   SET @Tries=1
   WHILE @Tries <=20
   BEGIN
   BEGIN TRY
   SET @UNDO_FOLDER = 'F:\MSSQL\UNDO\UNDO_' + @DATABASE_NAME + '.dat'
   SET @BACK_UP_STRING = 'RESTORE LOG ' + @DATABASE_NAME + ' FROM DISK = ''' + @TRAN_BACK_UP_PATH + @DATABASE_NAME + '\' + @BACKUP_FILE + ''' WITH STANDBY = ''' + @UNDO_FOLDER + ''',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10' 
   EXEC sp_executesql @BACK_UP_STRING
   SET @MOVE_CMD = 'MOVE /Y ' + @TRAN_BACK_UP_PATH + @DATABASE_NAME + '\' + @BACKUP_FILE + ' ' + @TRAN_BACK_UP_PATH + 'PROCESSED\' + @DATABASE_NAME + '\'
   EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @MOVE_CMD
   FETCH NEXT FROM backupFiles INTO @BACKUP_FILE
   SET @Tries =0
   BREAK;
   END TRY


   BEGIN CATCH
   --IF (ERROR_NUMBER() = 3101)
   SELECT ERROR_NUMBER()AS ErrorNumber
   SET @Tries = @Tries + 1
   IF @Tries >20
   BEGIN
   SET @MOVE_CMD = 'MOVE /Y ' + @TRAN_BACK_UP_PATH + @DATABASE_NAME + '\' + @BACKUP_FILE + ' ' + @TRAN_BACK_UP_PATH + 'PROCESSED\' + @DATABASE_NAME + '\'
   EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @MOVE_CMD
   FETCH NEXT FROM backupFiles INTO @BACKUP_FILE
   END
   END CATCH;
   END

END 

CLOSE backupFiles
DEALLOCATE backupFiles

SET @CONTROL_STRING = 'use ' + @DATABASE_NAME + ' INSERT INTO msdb.dbo.Logship_Control SELECT BackupDateTime, ''' + @DATABASE_NAME + ''',''' + @@servername + ''' FROM LogShip_Timestamp'
EXEC sp_executesql @CONTROL_STRING

FETCH dbs INTO @DATABASE_NAME 
END 

CLOSE dbs 
DEALLOCATE dbs 


SKIPPER:
CLEANUP: 

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Can anyone offer any advice on it and identify any issues in the script?

Thanks.

Comment: this will definitely get logged to eventvwr ,can you check the eventvwr log and also you could fire up a windbg and catch the exception in detail as well..further you could try to update ssms  and windows to latest version

Comment: What kind of error it's displaying? would you provide it?

Comment: I need to action what Thegameiswar has suggested but here is no direct error the management studio simply crashes and asks to restart. There are entrys in the event viewer for the crash.